# java.lang.NullPointerException in Main Activity

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I had a functioning program a few days ago, I switched a couple of buttons around an am now getting this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.jack.synthesiser, PID: 10903
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jack.synthesiser/com.example.jack.synthesiser.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.jack.synthesiser.MainActivity.initializeView(MainActivity.java:59)
                  at com.example.jack.synthesiser.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

It's probably a simple error but cant seem to find a fix for it, any help would be much appreciated. Heres my XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.jack.synthesiser.MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint ="Enter frequency"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"

    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="218dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText" />


<RadioGroup
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup">

    <RadioButton
        android:text="Sine"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton" />

    <RadioButton
    android:text="Square"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:layout_above="@+id/toggleButton"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/radioButton"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp" />

    <RadioButton
    android:text="Saw"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/radioButton2" />

</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp" />

<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/Volume"
    android:layout_marginStart="52dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button" />

<TextView
    android:text="@string/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Volume" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the main activity file:

```
package com.example.jack.synthesiser;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.widget.RadioButton;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements      View.OnClickListener, View.OnTouchListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

EditText frequencyInput;
TextView displayFrequency;
Button startStop;
RadioButton sine;
RadioButton square;
RadioButton saw;
PlaySine sineWave = new PlaySine();
PlaySquare squareWave = new PlaySquare();
PlaySaw sawWave = new PlaySaw();
//Filter attack = new Filter();
SeekBar amplitude;
AudioManager audioManager;
float curVolume, maxVolume, volume;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initializeView();
  //  volumeSounds();
}

//protected void  volumeSounds() {
//    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
//    curVolume = (float)audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
//    maxVolume = (float)audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

  //  volume = curVolume/maxVolume;
//}
private void initializeView () {

    frequencyInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    startStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    sine = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
    square = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
    saw = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
    //startStopSquare = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
    //startStopSaw = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton3);
    displayFrequency = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    startStop.setOnTouchListener(this);
    amplitude = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.Volume);
    audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    volume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    amplitude.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    //startStopSquare.setOnClickListener(this);
    //startStopSaw.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int frequency = Integer.parseInt(frequencyInput.getText().toString());
    displayFrequency.setText(String.valueOf(frequency));
    sineWave.setSine(frequency);
    squareWave.setSquareWave(frequency);
    sawWave.setSawWave(frequency);

}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    boolean on = ((startStop.isPressed()) && sine.isChecked());
    boolean sqOn = ((startStop.isPressed()) && square.isChecked());
    boolean sawOn =((startStop.isPressed()) && saw.isChecked());
    if (on) {
        sineWave.start();
    } else if (!on){
        sineWave.stop();
    }
    if (sqOn) {
        squareWave.start();
    } else if (!sqOn) {
        squareWave.stop();
    }
    if (sawOn) {
        sawWave.start();
    } else if (!sawOn) {
        sawWave.stop();
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because when you try to call `.setOnClickListener()` on one of the buttons the variable is `null`. Make sure you initialized the variable first using `findViewById()`, for example.

Comment: Thanks, found the error using your advice, much appreciated